# go-ethereum - geth - puppeth - ethstat remote server : docker: command not found

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I'm trying to setup a private ethereum test network using Puppeth (as [Péter Szilágyi demoed in Ethereum devcon three 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sXzxkODH-c)). I'm running it on a macbook pro (macOS Sierra).

When I try to setup the ethstat network component I get an **"docker configured incorrectly: bash: docker: command not found"** error. I have docker running and I can use it fine in the terminal e.g. docker ps.

Here are the steps I took:

```
What would you like to do? (default = stats)
 1. Show network stats
 2. Manage existing genesis
 3. Track new remote server
 4. Deploy network components
> 4

What would you like to deploy? (recommended order)
 1. Ethstats  - Network monitoring tool
 2. Bootnode  - Entry point of the network
 3. Sealer    - Full node minting new blocks
 4. Wallet    - Browser wallet for quick sends (todo)
 5. Faucet    - Crypto faucet to give away funds
 6. Dashboard - Website listing above web-services
> 1

Which server do you want to interact with?
 1. Connect another server
> 1

Please enter remote server's address:
> localhost
DEBUG[11-15|22:46:49] Attempting to establish SSH connection   server=localhost
WARN [11-15|22:46:49] Bad SSH key, falling back to passwords   path=/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa      err="ssh: cannot decode encrypted private keys"
The authenticity of host 'localhost:22 ([::1]:22)' can't be established.
SSH key fingerprint is xxx [MD5]
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
What's the login password for xxx at localhost:22? (won't be echoed)
>
DEBUG[11-15|22:47:11] Verifying if docker is available         server=localhost
ERROR[11-15|22:47:11] Server not ready for puppeth             err="docker configured incorrectly: bash: docker: command not found\n"
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there any documentation / tutorial describing how to setup this remote server properly. Or just on puppeth in general?
2. Can I not use localhost as "remote server address"
3. Any ideas on why the docker command is not found (it is installed and running and I can use it ok in the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

1. For the docker you have to use the docker-compose binary. You can find it [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).
2. Furthermore, you have to be sure that an ssh server is running on your localhost and that keys have been generated.
3. I didn't find any documentations for puppeth whatsoever.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but I still have the same problem. I have made sure that the keys are working and I can ssh to localhost without password. I also have docker-compose working.

Comment: Thanks for the rep. I would try the same procedure on a VM with Linux. Maybe it is a Mac related problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the root cause to this problem. The SSH daemon is compiled with a default path. If you `ssh` to a machine with a specific command (other than a shell), you get that default path. This does not include `/usr/local/bin` for example, where `docker` lives in my case.

I found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/a/585075:

- edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure it contains `PermitUserEnvironment yes` (you need to edit this with `sudo`)
- create a file `~/.ssh/environment` with the path that you want, in my case:

  `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

When you now run `ssh localhost env` you should see a `PATH` that matches whatever you put in `~/.ssh/environment`.